# MS ACCESS vba - error

Tags: vba, ms-access, select, recordset

I'm creating a MS Access report. I came across a small issue and I have no idea where it's going wrong. So what I'm trying to do is

1) Select everything from a query (query requires "TO" and "FROM" dates. I pass these values to the frmX which then gets referenced in the query). When i run a query by itself with the frmX open - it runs fine. 
2) Im trying to change some values in the data
3) Insert the new values into tempTable1

Here's my code:

```
dim rs1 as DAO.Recordset
dim rs2 as DAO.Recordset
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM [tempProvider-Detail]"

'Repopulating temp table
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryProvider-FINAL"

'Input Source
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from [qryProvider-Final]", , dbOpenSnapshot)

'Target Source
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from tempProvider-DETAIL", dbOpenDynamic)
```

What's interesting here is that it does not hang up on DoCMD.OpenQuery - however when I get to set rs1...... then it tells me that it expects 2 parameters. I don't know why - since the query already opened - and it works fine when I try opening it by itself it opens (with dates in frmX that i reference in the query).

Please help me out!

So I did this as Heinzi helped me.. still getting same error What is wrong??????

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryProvider-FINAL"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryProvider-FINAL")
qdf.Parameters(0) = [Forms]![frmX]![txtFrom]
qdf.Parameters(1) = [Forms]![frmX]![txtTo]
Set rs1 = qdf.OpenRecordset

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [qryProvider-FINAL];"

'Input Source
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, , dbOpenSnapshot) ---this is where it hangs up
```

Comment: Almost there. Just remove the two last lines of your current example (you have already set `rs1` in line 6, no need to open it again).

Comment: @Heinzi -- ok so I stop after set rs1 = qdf.openRecordset ? but I want to make sure I have all data selected!

Comment: I need to make sure it's all selected - as I'm going to move through the recordset and make edits as I go.

Comment: @Heinzi is right. rs1 is opened, so it makes no sense trying to open it again (even in the wrong way). The records are retrieved, there's nothing to "make sure". If you insist, loop through the recordset.

Comment: Why do you think `qdf.OpenRecordset` will *not* return all data?

Comment: @Heinzi --- i've never used that before - but I just did everything and it looks good!

Comment: @gustav well i need to loop through the recordset because I'm editing data - that's the only reason I'm doing this report with code - otherwise I would have done it off the query. It's not like I want to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference form controls when opening a recordset with CurrentDb.OpenRecordset. It's just not supported. Details can be found in the following MSDN article:

- [Everything About Using Parameters from Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa160564(office.11).aspx)

> The answer is that youre invoking the Jet engine in a different context here, and that makes all the difference. When you get data from a parameter query that uses a form to supply the parameter via the Access user interface, as in the earlier example, Access can evalute the expression involved and supply a value to Jet. When you get data from a parameter query that uses a form to supply the parameter via VBA, instead of through a form, the bits of Access that manage user interface matters arent involved. Consequently, Jet is passed the string "[Forms]![frmSelectCountry]![cboCountry]" instead of the value in cboCountry. Because Jet doesnt know how to evaluate the expression, it cant open the recordset.

Comment: @ heinzi what if instead i do something like dim strSQL as string       strSQL = "Select * from [qry];" and then set rs1=currentdbo.openrecordset(strSQL,,dbopensnapshot)

Comment: @FatBoySlim7: Won't make a difference. You need to provide the parameter values *in code*, as described in the article, if you need to open the recordset in code.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryProvider-FINAL")
    For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
        prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
    Next prm
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @Heinzi helped me out. I will save this for future use!